# Can't change UILabel text in method because of SIGABRT exception.What's wrong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, exception, uilabel

I' m creating a custom UITableViewCell view. I have a method for `UITableViewCell` and I have created `UILabel` `memberLabel` programmatically:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

static NSString * const cellIdentifier = @"cellMemberId";

CPNMemberCell *cell = (CPNMemberCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TeamCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = baseCell;
}

memberLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(32, 19, 183, 27)];
[cell addSubview:memberLabel];

NSString * const test = @"test input";
memberLabel.text = test;

  return cell;
}
```

So this code works quite well. But when I change test string value to string containing JSON response in MutableDictionary, all fails. I specially output that string to console log in order to be sure it is not empty or whatever. And I have an except during assigning
that string to UILabel:

```
NSString * const test = [members valueForKey:@"modelId"];
NSLog(@"Output: %@", test);
memberLabel.text = test;
```

I don't understand what's wrong: response correctly prints to the console, `UILabel` correctly displays text strings as in the first code block, but when I try to display string with that response I have a `SIGABRT` exception in the `main`.

Comment: `NSLog(@"Testing response in the console:", test);` isn't going to log `test`.  So how do you know that `test` exists and is something valid (not, eg, a dictionary)?

Comment: make sure that wat [ _members valueForKey:@"modelId"]; is a type NSString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what is the data type of `test` variable. Use:

```
NSLog(@"data type = %@", [[test class] description]);
```

Is it printing `data type = NSString`? If not, that is the issue.

Also try this,

```
NSString* test = [ _members valueForKey:@"modelId"];
NSLog(@"Testing response in the console: %@", test);
if ([test isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
  memberLabel.text = test;
} else {
  NSLog(@"test is not a string"); 
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't ever be necessary to log `[suchAndSuch description]` — NSLog already calls `description` on its object arguments to get a string.

Comment: @Chuck, That's true. I was just making it easy for him to get it printed the data type name so that later he can compare it with the real datatype name.

Comment: Why did you reproduce this line: `NSLog(@"Testing response in the console:", test);` ?

Comment: @HotLicks, My bad.. Even I missed it while copying from the code. Thanks for correcting. Updated the answer.

Comment: Yep, I'm betting that "test" is something bogus -- probably a dictionary.

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov, not a problem. everyone makes mistakes.. nothing to worry.